# Identify points in each quadrant of a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How do you divide a canvas into four quadrants (top-left, bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right) and then identify points drawn at random in each quadrant?

Here is my not so futile attempt:

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("showCanvas");
var myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

var xAxis = [];
var yAxis = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 600);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 350);
  var r = 5;
  xAxis.push(x);
  yAxis.push(y);
  myContext.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  myContext.closePath();
  myContext.fill();
}

var startingPoint = xAxis[0] + ", " + yAxis[0];
var endingPoint = xAxis[3] + ", " + yAxis[3];
var horizontalSlash = myCanvas.width / 2;
var verticalSlash = myCanvas.height / 2;
var remainder = horizontalSlash % verticalSlash;
```

```html
<canvas id="showCanvas"></canvas>
```

And the result should show up in these tags:

```html
<h3>The starting point of the line is: <label id="sumPoints">e.g. top, right</label></h3>
<h3>The end point of the line is: <label id="sumPoints">e.g. bottom, left</label></h3>
```

Comment: "_four quadrants_" is a bit ambiguous. You could define the cross point of the lines (virtual or true lines) dividing the canvas, then measure the angle between the random point and the cross point, and compare it to the angle the dividing lines create for each quadrant. This allows also diagonal quadrants without any changes to the script.

Comment: Four quadrants is top-left, bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right, Teemu. Since my canvas is a rectangle showing 4 randomly placed points in it, each point could appear in any one quadrant of the canvas (e.g. first point in top-left quad, second point in top-right quad, and so on), hence my attempt to divide the canvas into 4. If there's a better approach at locating my points in my canvas, I would highly appreciate that since I want to locate each point in the quadrant it is showing in and then place my data in an html tag? I don't know if I'm making sense...

Comment: Check the point's coordinates for being lower or greater than half the canvas width/height ...?

Comment: Thanks CBroe, your idea works!!!

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to check the point's coordinates is correct...
Here is an example using a bit of math.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("showCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const names = [
  ["top left",  "bottom left"],
  ["top right", "bottom right"]
]
var points = []

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var x = Math.random() * canvas.width
  var y = Math.random() * canvas.height
  var quadrant = names[Math.floor(x / (canvas.width / 2))][Math.floor(y / (canvas.height / 2))]

  points.push({ x, y, quadrant })
  ctx.arc(x, y, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillText(quadrant, x-8, y-8)
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

console.log(points[0])
```

```css
canvas {
  border:2px dotted gray;  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="showCanvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
```